# get Media metadata onActivityResult

Tags: android, metadata, onactivityresult

I have to select video or image on chooser intent like this

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                getIntent.setType("image/* video/*");

                Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                pickIntent.setType("image/* video/*");

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Media");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent});

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1);
```

Then I want to get the metadata of the file chosen in `onActivityResult()`
like height and width and length of the video and the size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get all your requirements.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever ret = new  MediaMetadataRetriever();
Bitmap bmp = null;      

try 
{
    ret.setDataSource("<<--Your retrieved data file-->>");
    bmp = ret.getFrameAtTime();
    videoHeight=bmp.getHeight();
    videoWidth=bmp.getWidth();
    videoSize = bmp.getAllocationByteCount()
}
```

Hope this helps, and let me know if any issue arises.

Comment: it wont it get this error
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/57 }} to activity {com.ts.tkllm/com.ts.tkllm.Chat}: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000`

Comment: Are you supplying the right data file path, that you get through onActivityResult() ?

Comment: thanks that worked for the videos
and i used drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.10.1 for images